# Flutter: shared preferences

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences, future

I have this function:

```
  Future<String> load(SharedPreferences prefs, String fileName) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String jsonString = prefs.getString(fileName) ?? "";
    if (jsonString.isNotEmpty) {
      return jsonString;
    }else{
      return ...
    }
  }
```

What should I return in the else case? I tried with "" but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: `String jsonString = prefs.getString(fileName) ?? "";` - is wrong, You have to do `String jsonString = (await prefs.getString(fileName)) ?? "";`

Comment: because, when I try to load, It gives me "FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Comment: If i put that await there, it will complain telling me "await only futures"

Comment: should I just put in the load an if condition like (!= "") ?

Comment: You are right about `await` I've just looked into different realization of prefs. It seems totally fine. Is problem exactly in `else` block?

Comment: I could solve easily writing an if condition (data != "") when I load this file, but was just curiosity if there was another way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". Namely, it depends on what exactly you are doing with the result of this function, and what a good empty default value means in that context.

Assuming you're [decoding](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-convert/JsonCodec/decode.html) the returned JSON string into a `Map<String, dynamic>`, then a good default value might be the empty map. In that case, you could reformulate your function as follows:

```dart
Future<String> loadJSON(final String fileName) async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String jsonString = prefs.getString(fileName);
  if (jsonString != null && jsonString.isNotEmpty) {
    return jsonString;
  }
  return "{}"; // default value
}

final String jsonString = await loadJSON("test.json");

final Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);
```

However, it probably makes more sense to reformulate this procedure as a slightly higher-level function returning actual map values:

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadData(final String fileName) async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final String jsonString = prefs.getString(fileName);
  if (jsonString != null && jsonString.isNotEmpty) {
    return json.decode(jsonString);
  }
  return Map(); // default value
}

final Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = await loadData("test.json");
```

Answer (score 36):

## Shared Preferences

In Flutter, Shared Preferences are used to store primitive data (`int`, `double`, `bool`, `string`, and `stringList`). This data is associated with the app, so when the user uninstalls your app, the data will also be deleted.

### Get the plugin

The [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) plugin from pub is a wrapper around Android `SharedPreferences` and iOS `NSUserDefaults`. You can get this plugin by adding the `shared_preferences` line to your *pubspec.yaml* file in the dependencies section.

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: '>=0.5.12+2 <2.0.0'
```

You can change the version number to whatever the [current](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) one is, but anything less than 2.0 should be compatible.

### Import the package

In whichever file you need the Shared Preferences, add the following import:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

## Reading and writing data

To get the shared preferences object you can do the following:

```dart
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

This will be used for all of the following examples.

#### int

- read: `final myInt = prefs.getInt('my_int_key') ?? 0;`
- write: `prefs.setInt('my_int_key', 42);`

#### double

- read: `final myDouble = prefs.getDouble('my_double_key') ?? 0.0;`
- write: `prefs.setDouble('my_double_key', 3.14);`

#### bool

- read: `final myBool = prefs.getBool('my_bool_key') ?? false;`
- write: `prefs.setBool('my_bool_key', true);`

#### string

- read: `final myString = prefs.getString('my_string_key') ?? '';`
- write: `prefs.setString('my_string_key', 'hello');`

#### stringList

- read: `final myStringList = prefs.getStringList('my_string_list_key') ?? [];`
- write: `prefs.setStringList('my_string_list_key', ['horse', 'cow', 'sheep']);`

## Removing data

You can remove any saved data by supplying the key name:

```dart
prefs.remove('my_int_key');
```

I rarely find a need to do that, though. I just overwrite the old data or ignore it. You shouldn't store any sensitive data in Shared Preferences.

## See also

- [Shared Preferences Service in Flutter for Code Maintainability](https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/shared-preferences-service-in-flutter-for-code-maintainability)
- Documentation: [Storing key-value data on disk](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value)
- [What are the ?? double question marks in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031804/what-are-the-double-question-marks-in-dart)
- [How to create an empty list in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031546/how-to-create-an-empty-list-in-dart)

Comment: This is the most amazing way you explained Shared Preference. If only this was how the documentation explained it. Thanks a lot!