# How to create an empty list in Dart

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I want to create an empty list for a Flutter project.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final myStringList = prefs.getStringList('my_string_list_key') ?? <empty list>;
```

I seem to remember there are multiple ways but one recommended way. How do I do it?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There are a few ways to create an empty list in Dart. If you want a growable list then use an empty list literal like this:

```
[]
```

Or this if you need to specify the type:

```
<String>[]
```

Or this if you want a non-growable (fixed-length) list:

```
List.empty()
```

#### Notes

- In the past you could use `List()` but this is now deprecated. The reason is that `List()` did not initialize any members, and that isn't compatible with null safe code. Read [Understanding null safety: No unnamed List constructor](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#no-unnamed-list-constructor) for more.
- [Effective Dart Usage Guide](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-collection-literals-when-possible)

Comment: Your are absolutely right,
But if you pass "growable: true" to List.empty(growable: true) then this will too become a growable list.

Comment: @KhizrAAShaikh, good point.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed Length List

```
 var fixedLengthList = List<int>.filled(5, 0);
 fixedLengthList[0] = 87;
```

Growable List

```
var growableList = [];
growableList.add(499);
```

For more refer [Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: These are for lists that aren't empty.

Comment: The growable list can be empty when declared. I've edited my answer to show that.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well when I tried `List.empty();`, but just initializing a list to `[]` works and makes it append-able.

Answer (score 2):

`List documents = [];`
empty list of documents

`List<'Student'> students = [];`
empty list of student object or model