# How to create an empty Set in Dart

Tags: flutter, collections, dart, set

I want to create an empty set for a Flutter project.

I tried this but I get an error:

```
Set<String> mySet = [];
```

> **Error**: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of
>   type 'Set'.

I found an [old question of mine for lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031546/how-to-create-an-empty-list-in-dart) but it doesn't apply to sets.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create an empty Set a number of different ways. For a local variable use a set literal:

```
var mySet = <String>{};
```

And for a non-local variable you can use the type annotated form:

```
Set<String> mySet = {};
```

#### Notes

- Empty [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031546/how-to-create-an-empty-list-in-dart) and [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608681/how-to-create-an-empty-map-in-dart):

  ```
  var myList = <String>[];
  var myMap = <String, int>{};
  ```
- Set literals require Dart 2.2 minimum, which you can change in your pubspec.yaml file if your current setting is below 2.2:

  ```
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"
  ```
- [Sets documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets)

Comment: It has nothing to do with local or non-local. Both ways can be used in both local and non-local scopes. It's just two different ways of declaring variables. One with type, one without

Comment: @Ivo, that's true. Both are permissible as far as the language is concerned. What I stated above are merely coding conventions promoted (I believe) by the Effective Dart guide. (See https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#types). It's been a while since I've read this thoroughly, though, and I might have been wrong to start with, so correct me if I've misunderstood the guides. And feel free to ignore the guides even if I have understood them correctly.

Comment: you're right. It does seem to be the coding convention

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set()` from dart:core.

Source: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/Set/Set.html.