# How to create an empty Map in Dart

Tags: dart, collections, hashmap

I'm always forgetting how to create an empty map in Dart. This doesn't work:

```dart
final myMap = Map<String, dynamic>{};
```

This is ok:

```dart
final myMap = Map<String, dynamic>();
```

But I get a warning to use collection literals when possible.

*I'm adding my answer below so that it'll be here the next time I forget.*

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can create an empty `Map` by using a map literal:

```dart
{}
```

However, if the type is not already known, it will default to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`, which defeats type safety. In order to specify the type for a local variable, you can do this:

```dart
final myMap = <String, int>{};
```

And for non-local variables, you can use the type annotation form:

```dart
Map<String, int> myMap = {};
```

#### Notes:

- [DO use collection literals when possible.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-collection-literals-when-possible)
- [Omit type annotations for local variables.](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html)

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I remember the syntax:

`{}` is a literal, and `()` performs an invocation<sup>1</sup>. `T{}` is illegal syntax, and `T()` invokes the unnamed constructor for `T`.  It doesn't matter what `T` is, whether it's `Map<K, V>` or `String` or any other class.

`{}` is a literal, but what kind of literal?  Is it a `Set` or a `Map`?  To distinguish between them, you should express the type.  The way to express types for generics is put types in angle brackets: `<K, V>{}` for a `Map<K, V>`, and `<E>{}` for a `Set<E>`.

The same goes for `List`s: `[]` is a literal, and you can specify the type with angle brackets: `<E>[]`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Obviously there are [many other uses for `{}` and `()` in other contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61948369/).