# Ternary operator in Flutter to return List<Widget>

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to return a list of 2 widgets depending on the `swapped` value. I tried:

```
Container(child: Row(children: swapped? [a, b]: [b, a],),
```

where `a` and `b` are `Widget`:

```
Widget a = ...
Widget b = ...
```

But I'm getting

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'bool'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

`swapped` is `bool`

I also tried

```
children: swapped? List<Widget>([a, b]): List<Widget>([b, a])
```

and got

```
The argument type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
```

Comment: Hi there i tried the same and it worked for me and the error for you may be  semmicolon you are using [b: a] instead of comma

Comment: @AzadPrajapat edited, it was a mistake. Still have the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced similar problems when using the ternary operator in Colors which results in similar error, so what's the solution?

Wrap your condition of ternary in parenthesis like below

`Container(child: Row(children: (swapped? [a, b]: [b, a]),),)`

What was the real pronlem:
As your were writing condition to check that is swapped is true or not the dart was just going through boolean first but as everyone and even dart know that book!= List then it rejects your code and hence results in an error.

Conclusion :

Use parenthesis with ternary operators whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the following code on dartpad its working

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 bool swapped =true;
    Widget a=Text("2");
    Widget b = Text("4");

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: swapped? [a,b]: [b,a],
                  ), 
      ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'bool'.

I can't seem to reproduce your problem with DartPad, but it sounds like you're running into an ambiguity between the ternary operator and the [new null-aware subscript operator](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/376) that was introduced with Dart's new null-safety feature.

> I also tried
>
> ```
> children: swapped? List<Widget>([a, b]): List<Widget>([b, a])
> ```
>
> and got
>
> ```
> The argument type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
> ```

You get that error because `List<Widget>([a, b])` does not do what you think it does.  Dart doesn't support overloaded functions, so you're invoking the (now deprecated) [`List` constructor that takes a single length argument](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.html) and are attempting to pass a `List` as the length.

[What you actually want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609471/), which I think should resolve the original ambiguity, is:

```dart
children: swapped ? <Widget>[a, b]: <Widget>[b, a],
```

(Since I can't reproduce your problem, it'd be useful to know what version of Dart you're using and if you could provide a minimally reproducible example.)