# Is there a way to use shared preference on a like button

Tags: image, flutter, favorites

I have a favorite image button for images which turns red when clicked but it doesn't store it, when I reopen the image it's not liked. So I was wondering if we could give shared preference on it to store the liked button.Does anyone know how it can be done?

```
the complete code-
class FavoriteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteWidgetState createState() => _FavoriteWidgetState();
}
class _FavoriteWidgetState extends State<FavoriteWidget> {
  bool liked = false;
  _pressed() {
    setState(()  {
      liked = !liked;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(liked ?Icons.favorite: Icons.favorite_border,
                color: liked ? Colors.red :Colors.grey ),
            onPressed: () => _pressed(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This may assist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831605/flutter-shared-preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin to persist whether the favorite button has been pressed or not, and then restore the persisted value when the `Widget` initializes.

```dart
class FavoriteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteWidgetState createState() => _FavoriteWidgetState();
}

class _FavoriteWidgetState extends State<FavoriteWidget> {
  static const likedKey = 'liked_key';

  bool liked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _restorePersistedPreference();
  }

  void _restorePersistedPreference() async {
    var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var liked = preferences.getBool(likedKey) ?? false;
    setState(() => this.liked = liked);
  }

  void _persistPreference() async {
    setState(() => liked = !liked);
    var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.setBool(likedKey, liked);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: liked == null
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      liked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: liked ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    onPressed: _persistPreference,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: All the images are getting liked If I try liking one image

Comment: Then you should store an unique key that each image has, like an ID.

Comment: Can you explain it in detail how to do it?

Comment: For sharing image - onPressed: () => _shareImage(imgPath)),I am giving imgPath as the key to share that particular image.Should I give the same to this too and if yes where to put it exactly?